# Geoloqi Sampel Code: IOS code sign error

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run sample code on my real iphone ios6. There is an error like this "

The identity 'iPhone Developer: Aaron Parecki (UR6C55S2E6)' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains"

But if I used the simulator, it seemed fine. Is there any way to fix this and test the sample code on my device? I have already bought the developer account and provisioned the device. Other program is running well.

Thanks.

Comment: To run code on your actual device you need to be a $99 registered ios developer. Are you? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson or jailbreak the phone and fake codesign the binary using `ldid -S`.

Comment: If you're already a developer and have the device provisioned, you should only need to change the signing identity in the build to your own. What version of XCode are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a developer account , then set up an App Id , create provisions for your app and then use the provision files in your project.

You get the error because you neither have the provision files nor the keychain pair of the developer ie,Aaron,  installed on your system, You need to have your own and then try running and it will work fine.